# Refinement of the hierarchy theorem of a complexity class

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Say $\mathrm{CTIME}$ is some complexity measure, syntactic or semantic (e.g. $\mathrm{DTIME}$ or $\mathrm{BPTIME}$).
If we already know that for some $f(n) = \omega(n)$, $\mathrm{CTIME}(n) \subsetneq \mathrm{CTIME}(f(n))$, then, by a standard padding argument [[KV87]](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/ftp/reports/cs-reports/1985-1989/8510-CS.pdf), for any $h(n)$ such that $h^c(n) = \Omega(f(n))$ with some constant $c$,

\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{CTIME}(n) \supseteq \mathrm{CTIME}(h(n)) &\implies \mathrm{CTIME}(h^i(n)) \supseteq \mathrm{CTIME}(h^{i+1}(n)) \\
& \implies \mathrm{CTIME}(n) \supseteq \mathrm{CTIME}(f(n)).
\end{align*}
Therefore $\mathrm{CTIME}(n) \subsetneq \mathrm{CTIME}(h(n))$. As an example, authors in [[KV87]](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/ftp/reports/cs-reports/1985-1989/8510-CS.pdf) show that $\mathrm{BPTIME}(n^{\log n}) \subsetneq \mathrm{BPTIME}(2^{n^\epsilon})$ from $\mathrm{BPTIME}(n) \subsetneq \mathrm{BPTIME}(2^{O(n)})$.

Can we further improve this result as follows? (My intuition is NO but I don't know why. Maybe it has something to do with whether we can well order all probable "nice" functions, by defining $\textrm{"}f \leq g\textrm{"}\  :=\   \textrm{"}f=O(g)\textrm{"}$.)

> We only need $h$ to satisfy that the union of "intervals"
>   $$
>   [\Omega(t(n)), O(h(t(n))]
> $$
>   over all time-constructable $t(n)$ "covers" [$\Omega(n), O(f(n))$].

Suppose, throughout this process, we only consider "nice" function constructed by recursively applying arithmetic operation, $2^x$ or $\log x$ (e.g. $n^{\log n/\log \log n}$).